# Dynamically Align image in the edge of the UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

What I want to achieve is this:

[image]

What I currently tried is this:

```
[button setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 180)];
  button.semanticContentAttribute = UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight;
```

This works but I need something that will adjust dynamically where it will constantly retain a 10 margin in the right.

My button is in the header section and each header section contains different text, so possibly that I might have longer text in which resulting in a different inset.

As much as possible I don't want to hardcode the inset of the image on the headersection.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/mta452/UIView-TouchHighlighting

Comment: @ChiragKothiya that is irrelevant.